# Convert Minutes to Seconds in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

How do I convert the duration from Minutes to seconds . After the below step, I get the result in Minutes for Duration and I wanted to convert it to seconds for example - 00.04.19 to 259 seconds

````
| extend duration = ((EndTime - StartTime)/60)
| summarize duration= avg(duration) by EndTime```
````

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic

For example:

`print timespan(01:23:45) / 1s`